# Validate Rails model just when some method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

For some reason I need to run this validation

```
validates_presence_of :user_id
```

just when some method is called

```
def publish # this method does not save nor update record
            # so validations are not run
  ...
end
```

I have solved it this way:

```
# model
validates_presence_of :user_id, if: :going_to_publish
attr_accessor :going_to_publish

# when calling publish
post.going_to_publish = true
post.publish
```

Is there a way to remove that flag variable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any necessity here.

If you publish a post, the post obj must be **persistent**. So the `publish` method must call `create`/`save` method inside.

If such methods called, the validation rules will be called as well.

*add*

Validation works for update as well

> Creating and saving a new record will send an SQL INSERT operation to the database. Updating an existing record will send an SQL UPDATE operation instead. Validations are typically run before these commands are sent to the database. If any validations fail, the object will be marked as invalid and Active Record will not perform the INSERT or UPDATE operation.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#when-does-validation-happen

Comment: actually publish method does not update record, I don't know how I get to this mess.

Comment: Then what will this method do?

Comment: hmm, to explain situation better I am creating `reviews` referencing post from AJAX so I save post before, and then I create reviews pointing to that post. When I publish post I call `notify_reviewers`, and I want to validate post in that case not the first.

Comment: I suppose `validates_presence_of :user_id, on: :update` should work, what do you think?

Comment: actually `user_id` is not the problem, is `reviewers`

Comment: @juanpastas, validation works on update as well by default. see my update. For anything related to interface but not only memory, you need a persist object from db. Besides, if you don't change the post in review, you don't need to validate it which you have done that before.

Comment: yes, but actually I could not explain myself clearly. I edited question to state clearly that publish does not update nor save record.